# Still the counter variable inside the for loop is not changing/counting in real time why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to click the button over and over again to see on screen the counting update. But i want that it will be updated in real time when the FOR loop is working.

In the top of my MainActivity i added:

```
private TextView text;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
private int counter = 0;
```

Then inside the onCreate i added:

```
params =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


        ipaddresses = IpAddresses.GenerateIps();


        addListenerOnButton();
```

Then in the button click method addListenerOnButton:

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {

                                try
                                {
                                    counter++;
                                    text.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {

                                            text.setText("Checking Connection With Ip: " + ipaddresses[counter]);
                                            text.setLayoutParams(params);
                                        }
                                    });

                                    response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    String err = e.toString();
                                }

                                if (response!=null)
                                {

                                    try
                                    {
                                        final String a = new String(response,"UTF-8");


                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                text.setText(a);
                                            }
                                        });

                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                    }

                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                    break;

                                }

                                else
                                {

                                }
                        }
                        if (response == null)
                        {
                            text.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

But i'm facing two problems:

1. When i'm doing inside the loop inside the FOR loop:

   text.setLayoutParams(params);

Then textView2 is jumping change it's position to the top of the screen.
But i wanted it to keep staying on same height level and only to be moving to the left so all the text will be on this line.

Second problem is that now i'm using counter as the variable to count.
But the counter is not counting in real time when the FOR loop is working i need to click the button over and over again to see on screen the changes.
I want to make that without clicking all the time it will show on screen the counting.

```
text.setText("Checking Connection With Ip: " + ipaddresses[counter]);
```

For some reason instead automatic on real time show me on screen:

Checking Connection With Ip: 10.0.0.2 then 
Checking Connection With Ip: 10.0.0.3 then
Checking Connection With Ip: 10.0.0.4

I need to click on the button to see this changes.

1. Why the textView2 is not moving to the left but to the top up ?
2. How to use the counter variable to count and display it in real time ?

If i try to use the for(int i = 0
If i will use the I variable it will give me error and if i change the I to final then i can't use it in the for(i = 0....since you can't assign final variables.

So i tried to use the counter but it dosen't show the progress the counting in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to update views from a thread. Call runOnUIThread() from your counter thread to update the text view.